# How can I get the boost/Serialization-libs compiled in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: boost

Is there any way to get the Serialization-libs compiled? I really need those and I don't wanna install an older version of Visual Studio (got 2013).

Comment: You should provide a few more details:  What you have tried, what version of boost, what problem you ran into.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use the boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp header (boost 1.55). When I try to build it, I get the error: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Datei "libboost_serialization-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden.   Which means the .lib cannot be opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While most components of boost are header-only, a couple of them depend on separately compiled libraries.  To compile them just follow the [instructions here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source).  After having them compiled, you can include the header files as usual, the linker picks the required libraries automatically.

Comment: Thx for that idea. I'm confused about the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534622/boost-1-55-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013 because somebody wrote there: "Known Bugs with Visual Studio 2013" - Serialization can't compile because of a missing include.

Comment: It does work with the latest boost from git.  There appears to be a bug and a patch for that issue in 1.55: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9332